# custom core controller not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a core controller named `Role_Admin` and set the config prefix

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'Role_';
```

Here is the code for the `Role_Admin.php` in the `core` folder

```
class Role_Admin extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {

    }
}
```

In the controller folder when I write

```
class admin extends Role_Admin { ... }
```

I get

> Fatal error: Class 'Role_Admin' not found

Is something wrong in what I am doing.

edit: (i created a quick fix that is much better, any new core file that you create just extend the MY_Controller. Then in your controller directory you can extend any Core controller that you created

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            //include custom core classes
            $core_path = DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/application/core';
            $this->load->helper('file');

            foreach(get_filenames($core_path) as $file) {
                if ($file != 'MY_Controller.php') {
                    if(file_exists($file)) {
                        include_once($file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: where have you put this controller and which version are you using?

Comment: You have saved `Role_Admin.php` in `application/core/` and not in `system/core/`, right ?

Comment: air4x, yes   .... reheel i am using the latest as of now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting you have for `$config['subclass_prefix']` is fine, but your file name is incorrect. CI is looking for the file `Role_Controller.php`, not `Role_Admin.php`.

There's an easier way to do this, and although it might appear to be a hack it is totally legit. Go back to the `MY_` prefix, create `MY_Controller.php`, and in that file, just define the controller classes you want to use. You actually don't even need a `MY_Controller` class. Example:

```
// application/core/MY_Controller.php
class Role_Admin extends CI_Controller {}
class AnotherClass extends Role_Admin {}
class SomeOtherClass extends AnotherClass {}
```

All these classes will be available for your controllers to extend.

Comment: have all these classes in that one file?

Comment: Yes, you can. It's what I do, but my base controllers are pretty lean.

Comment: Does my answer satisfy your question or is there still a problem? The issue with "custom core controller not found" was that you needed `Role_Controller.php`, not `Role_Admin.php.`, if that was not the case then do let me know. The design of your classes is a separate concern.